# Execute test suites in a specific order

Tags: maven, testng, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm using the maven-failsafe plugin to trigger testng suites with configuration similar to

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
 <file>src/test/resources/suites/somesuite.xml</file>
 <file>src/test/resources/suites/anothersuite.xml</file>
 <file>src/test/resources/suites/yetanothersuite.xml</file>
</suiteXmlFiles>
```

but the suites or the tests within them are not getting executed in the correct order. Is there a way to specifiy that the suites should be executed in the below order

1. somesuite.xml
2. anothersuite.xml
3. yet another suite.xml

I don't care about the order in which the tests within a suite is executed, but would like to execute one suite only after the previous one has completed. Is there some configuration which I could use to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a seperate testng.xml file and add something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file
            path="path-to\suite1.xml" />
        <suite-file
            path="path-to\suite2.xml" />
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

And then add this testng.xml file to your maven suite